# Is it possible to configure the "PHP built-in web server" to process PHP codes that are internal to an HTML page?

Tags: php, html, web, httpserver, built-in

Since the PHP built-in web server does not consider ".htaccess" files
"AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html" (or anything like that), how can I configure it to process PHP codes, embedded in the HTML inside its curly braces (<?php ... ? >)?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Just rename all relevant files to .php

Answer (score 2):

Renaming your HTML files to have a ".php" extension is what makes most sense. However, if you really do not want to do this, or can't, there is a way.

You could use a router script (see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) in which you process the file as PHP.  For example create a file called **router.php**:

```
<?php
$extensions = array("html", "htm");

$path = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (in_array($ext, $extensions)) {
    $file = __DIR__ . $path;
    $data = file_get_contents($file);
    return eval('?> ' . $data); // this is where the data is processed. 
}
return false; // return false if the file does not have a .html or .htm extension.
```

Then run your built in web server using this file: `php -S localhost:8000 router.php`.

Next, go to your browser and visit an HTML file, for example *index.html* on: `localhost:8000/index.html`. If your HTML file contains any PHP code, this will now be executed by the `eval()` function in your `router.php`.

**BE CAREFUL:** This is not something you should use in production as this can pose a serious security threat!

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations, and I agree with all of them!

Thanks for your code, it's more elegant and streamlined than I tried, and it works, but if there's a possibility I'd like it to be by server configuration.

Although I don't think that's even possible!

Comment: I am afraid you cannot do this without any extra script like this one I posted. Apparently in Apache you have this setting for the handler, but for the built-in PHP server, I don't think there is this option. You could pass in config through a file (php.ini) with `php -S localhost:8000 -c php.ini`, but again, I don't think there is an option you could set in this file that would get you the result you want.

Comment: I understand, and I'm sorry... But what configuration would have to be done in php.ini?
Thank you so much!

Comment: See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php. However, like I said, I am pretty sure there is no way to set it to handle HTML files as if they were PHP files.

Comment: Dirk J. Faber, Thanks for your support! Now I am convinced of the impossibility!

Answer (score 1):

It would be so much easier to use LAMP stack. It is not recommended to use PHP built-in web server for production. You can find the warning below in [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

"**Warning** This web server is designed to aid application development. It may also
be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations that are run in
controlled environments. It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It
should not be used on a public network."

You can't use PHP in HTML files. Or not atleast without any major configuration. However you can write HTML in PHP files.

Comment: I appreciate your comments and recommendations, and I agree with all of them, but in this specific case, I need the built-in server, if possible, to handle the "PHP" codes inside the HTML pages. Grateful!